# SpringBoot : parameterize resolving entity relations by different GET requests

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

i would like to parameterize fetching and returning an entity relation bydifferent GET requests on the entity. 
Is there a configuration way to achieve that, combining fetch strategy and json inclusion ?

example : how to return / not return the list of Bs by different Gets on A.

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<B> listBs ; 
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private A a ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference`

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<B> listBs ; 
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private A a ; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Golam, i want to control the returning of the list of Bs in two different Get requests on A. i don't think JsonManagedReference, JsonBackReference fit here.